# get field value using query and convert particular character into uppercase

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to write query that retrive all employee names. If any employee name contain 'a' character convert into uppercase.

All this i want to do only with query.

for ex.:

> **Eid Ename**
>
> 1   ganesh
>
> 2   ram
>
> 3   sheen
>
> 4    aadhar

Should be like: (expected)

> **Eid Ename**
>
> 1   gAnesh
>
> 2   rAm
>
> 3   sheen
>
> 4    AAdhAr

Comment: Should your expected result AAdhar be AAdhAr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [replace](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function

```
select replace(name, 'a', 'A') from table
```